# How connect two SQL tables that don't have common columns using third table, which contains columns of those both

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to build SQL query to get all users metadata (`meta`) from `signup` table which `id` is in `courses_history` table.

The problem is that `signup` table don't have `user_id` but does have `user_login` and `courses_history` have only `user_id`.

There is the third table - `users`, which holds `user_id` and `user_login` but I don't know how to connect all 3 table in the right way

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (`user_id` int, `user_login` varchar(7), `description` varchar(55));

INSERT INTO users
    (`user_id`, `user_login`, `description`)
VALUES
    (100, 'user_1', 'userdataxxxx'),
    (201, 'user_2', 'userdatayyyy'),
    (301, 'user_3', 'userdatazzzz');

CREATE TABLE signups
    (`id` int, `user_login` varchar(7), `meta` varchar(55));

INSERT INTO signups
    (`id`, `user_login`, `meta`)
VALUES
    (1, 'user_1', 'metaxxxxx'),
    (2, 'user_2', 'metayyyy'),
    (3, 'user_3', 'metazzzzz');

CREATE TABLE courses_history
    (`id` int, `user_id` int, `stuff` varchar(55), `course_id` int);

INSERT INTO courses_history
    (`id`, `user_id`, `stuff`)
VALUES
    (1, 301, 'stuffxxx', 10),
    (2, 301, 'stuffyyyy', 11),
    (3, 100, 'stuffzzzz', 22);
    (4, 201, 'stuffzzzz', 66);
    (5, 201, 'stuffzzzz', 88);
```

Thanks

Comment: use inner join. think of it like making a bridge .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ch.id, u.user_login, su.meta
FROM signups su
INNER JOIN users u ON su.user_login = u.user_login 
INNER JOIN courses_history ch ON u.user_id = ch.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    s.meta 
FROM
    signups AS s
    INNER JOIN courses_history AS ch
    ON s.id = ch.id
    INNER JOIN users AS u
    ON ch.user_id = u.user_id
```

You can pull whatever data you want out of all three of the tables with this, but I believe this illustrates the point well enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
From 1st_table
Inner join CommonTable On common_field = 1stField
Inner join 2nd table on CommonField = 2ndfield
```

Comment: You should add some text explaining what this answer does and why it provides a solution to the specific problem. Code dumps are rarely ever of use to other people.